# Wordpress: If the_category != "category2"

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

Quick Wordpress question. Is it possible to check against a specific category, so not to display it? I tried this, but my category was still being echoed (no errors).

```
 <?php if (the_category() != "NAMEOFMYCATEGORY") { the_category(' | '); } ?>
```

Or would I need to work with a new function?

To clarify: I want to HIDE 1 specific category so it doesn't show up.

Comment: Please use the function `var_dump` on the output of `the_category()` end post the result.

Comment: How exactly? I do have this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_category

Comment: I meant `var_dump( the_category() );`

Comment: Doesn't do anything, just displays my categories like usual.

Comment: Remember that functions like `the_category()` echo the output, not return it.

Comment: How are you querying for the posts?

Comment: You can hide with CSS, too. Would that be an option?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work:

```
<?php
foreach (get_the_category() as $category) {
    if ( $category->name !== 'FORBIDDEN CATEGORY NAME' ) {
        echo '<a href="' . get_category_link($category->term_id) . '">' .$category->name . '</a><br />'; //Markup as you see fit
    }
```

The name is Caps sensitive.

Comment: Thanks! This works great. I would like to LINK (a href) to my categories also, is this possible? This just displays the name only. If not, too bad!

Comment: @Linkjuice57 Code updated. If this is what you are looking for please reward the bounty, if not I'll look into it.

Comment: Thank you!! This is just what I wanted :). Thanks for the great help.

Answer (score 4):

Why not to use the codex version?

```
if (is_home()) {query_posts('cat=-1,-2,-3'); }  // excludes categories 1 2 3
```

also do you remember in_category() ?

```
if (have_posts() && (!in_category('3')) {

//do domething;

} else // do different loop
```

Comment: +1 Works with numeric ID, the Name or the Slug. Works also with multiple of them in form of an array. You could add links to the codex to improve your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to do something like this, if i got ur question correctly :)

```
foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {
   if($category->cat_name = 'mycheckcatname')
   {
   DO THIS
   }
   else
   {
   Do THAT
   }
}
```

**NEW EDIT**--

or this is what else u are looking for ---

```
<?php if (is_category('Category A')) : ?>
<p>This is the text to describe category A</p>
<?php elseif (is_category('Category B')) : ?>
<p>This is the text to describe category B</p>
<?php else : ?>
<p>This is some generic text to describe all other category pages, 
I could be left blank</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: @Linkjuice57 let me know if this is what u want or ur referring to something else :)

Comment: First code does not work. I get all my categories, only their anchortekst is all "CATEGORYNAME". And it echo's everything twice. The second function is for displaying information relevant to a category. What I am trying to do is HIDE a specific category (don't echo if it equals Category X).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    $categories =  get_categories('');
    $excluded_categories = array('Sem Categoria','Uncategorized');

    foreach  ($categories as $category) {
        if(in_array( $category->cat_name, $excluded_categories)){
            continue;
        }
        echo $category->name;
    }                                     
?>
```